# How to make a time check

Tags: php, laravel, time

I want to make a check in such a ways:

Current Time: `1220`

If a user places an order with a pickup time of `1215` it should give and error.

If he places it at `1250` it should proceed.

What I have tried is I made an if statement for `hours_entered>Current_hour`, but for minutes I'm a bit confused as to how can I achieve this. I'm doing this on Laravel and this is what I have done so far:

```
$currentTime=Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
$currentHour=date('H');
$currentMinutes=date('i');
if($request->hours>=$currentHour && $request->minutes>currentMinutes){
     Alert::error('You have entered an invalid time','Invalid Time');
     return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more info? Let's say, current time is 1pm, user places order for a pickup at 1.15, that's an error, and if he places the order at 1.50, that's okay? So is there a fixed number of minutes that should pass, before user places the order with a pickup?

Comment: Yeah a minimum of 40 minutes must be added to the current minutes

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice there are two possibilities where a time is valid:

If the reuqested hour is below the current hour it's always valid. If the requested hour is the same as the current hour, the requested minute must be lower than the current minute.

```
if( $reqHour < $currentHour || 
    ($reqHour === $currentHour && $reqMinute <= $currentMinute)
) {
  // passes
}
```

Now this must be inversed to have the "failed" case:

If the requested hour is above the current hour, it's always invalid. If the requested hour is the same as the current, it's invalid if the requested minute is higher than the current minute:

```php
if( $reqHour > $currentHour ||
   ($reqHour === $currentHour && $reqMinute > $currentMinute)
) {
  // Invalid case
}
```

If the date is also a thing to check consider using a comparism of `DateTime`-objects or similar.

Comment: The issue is that i want to have a check that the user must place the order with the pickup time in the future it cannot be in the past

Answer (score 0):

in $request->time take the requested time from the user in DateTime format, then compare like below. I hope it will work for you.

$valid_time_till=now()->addMinutes(50);

if($request->time < $valid_time_till){

```
 .........
```

}